# Setting connection string programmatically to obscure db password

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms, dataset, connection-string

I am using a TableAdapter in a dataset in Vb.net winforms (connected to a mysql server) to allow integration of a Devexpress scheduler - I have been using this method for some time; while I know of many of the security flaws of vb.net including decompiling and packet sniffing plain text communication; I am trying to lock down security as much as I can which brings me to my current problem.

The dataset was set up to connect using the .net framework data provider for mysql which requests a Server address, username, password, and DB file - I then get the option of "saving the login credentials in the connection string" or "setting the login credentials in my programming code" for sake of time previously I saved the login credentials.

this adds a setting file (connectionstring)

```
server=mysqlserveraddress.com;user id=mysqluser;password=mysqlpassword;database=mysqldb;persistsecurityinfo=True
```

which also means these credentials are saved in plain text in the installation folder for my program

I am trying to transition to including this connectionstring in my programming code however I do not know how to approach it - for non-dataset transactions I have already declared public const in a module which includes the credentials

```
'database variables
Public Const dbserver As String = "mysqlserveraddress.com"
Public Const dbuser As String = "mysqluser"
Public Const dbpassw As String = "mysqlpassword"
Public Const dbfile As String = "mysqldb"
```

and I create the connections when needed.

How do I programmatically enter the connection string so it is not visible to the lay-person.

Comment: This link might help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Put your connection string in the app.config file where it belongs.  Then, when you deploy to the production environment, change the password there and restrict who is allowed to view and edit that file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you want to to set the user id and password attributes of an existing connection string at run time?  If so then you can use the appropriate connection string builder.  I don't use MySQL and Connector/Net but it should look something like this:

```
Dim builder As New MySqlConnectionStringBuilder(partialConnectionString)

builder.UserId = userId
builder.Password = password

Dim fullConnectionString As String = builder.ConnectionString
```

Anyone who decompiles your code is going to see that data though.  You might consider just storing the whole lot in the config file but encrypting it.  For more info on that, check this out:

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?532768-NET-2-0-Protected-Configuration-(Encrypting-Config-Files)